# How to Access all user achievements

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I read a little about android achievements system, and I would like to know if I can get a list of all the achievements that a user has (in every game he played).
In my application I want to get the user achievements and treat to him accordingly
Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Google has not made this possible. But why would you need this? Shouldn't you be rewarding for things in your app, instead of checking what has been accomplished in other apps? Not only this, but that's super easy to hack. Let's say your audience, say they're a developer. They could easily create an app with 100s of achievements just to get ahead in your game. Just food for thought.

Comment: My application is not a game.
I want to reward users for their achievements in other games (in point they can use for other things)